# Ethereum transaction order

Tags: solidity, transactions

I have a contract for saving some data with a time stamp. Saving data needs to have later time stamp than the last saved data. User will send the data to blockchain in correct order, lets say like this:

```
for (var data in dataSet){
 var timestamp = DateTime.Now;
 sendDataToBlockchain(data, timestamp);
}
```

This makes lots of transaction. Data will be sent from one address. Will the data be proceeded and saved in correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions sent from the same account have a strict ordering rule. The nonce must be incremented for each transaction. So yes, if you send the transactions all from the same account in a certain order, they'll be mined in that same order.